# converting pipe seperated raw data to xlsx using xlsxwriter module of python

Tags: python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I'm new to python and trying to write a small code to convert raw pipe seperated data to xlsx. Details as below :

raw data
a|b|c|d|
.
.
.
1000s of row

expected output
a b c d {each representing one cell in xlsx}

My code:

```
workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook('ABC.xlsx')
worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet()
input_file=(raw_data.txt,'r')

row=0
col=0

for line in input_file:
    line=line.split('|')
    workseet.write(row,col,line)
    row +=1
worsheet.close()
```

The output that i'm getting is :
a b c d (all in single cell)

Any pointers on what i'm missing here will be helpful.

Comment: Why not iterate over the `line` list: `for col, value in enumerate(line): worksheet.write(row, col, value)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you it worked!!. In a case, suppose dataset is huge in raw file (both rows n columns), in that case iterating over list (after splitting as per delimiter) might consume a long time to write to spreadsheet. Isn't it ? Any alternatives in such cases.

Comment: If you find that performance is a problem, you could look into [the docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/index.html) to see what other options there are. Alternatively, use Excel's own data importer, which can handle CSV formats.